# Can one question posted on this Law site be simultaneously posted on the Politics site for alternative input?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I suppose there might legitimately exist different legal and political takes on some questions we have such as, "Does the President have free rein to discredit the mass media?" There are both legal and political ramifications to that! If so,

- would it be acceptable to post the same question on both sites?
- can one thread be acceptably made to link back to the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't do better than [the answer to this very FAQ on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/241697).  Helpful clarification on that guidance is also in [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87739/241697).

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) answer - posting the same question is a no go. However, posting the same hypothetical situation and asking here about the legal aspects and there about the political ones is fine i.e. two questions about the same facts.

Answer (score 1):

To give another Meta.SE a link: [Feature suggestion: Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with “crossover questions” between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/178179).

Rationale: Stack Exchange is fragmented into many websites, and inevitably some of them overlap. As a result it'd make sense to allow a question to be visible from more than one Stack Exchange website at once (but without duplicating the content, unlike what https://stats.stackexchange.com/, https://ai.stackexchange.com/ and http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ are doing for example for questions on artificial intelligence / machine learning).